# Help identifying printing color technology and style

Tags: print-design, terminology

I'm looking for the correct printing terms to describe the attached image of an early trading card. It seems to be some form of chromolithography. Does this sound correct? Are there more specific terms to describe the color stippled style? Thx.

[image: Printed card showing rose-combed dorking cock]

Comment: I would say yes, you are correct, it looks like chromolithographic print.  Here's [another example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trading_card#/media/File:Adrian_%22Cap%22_Anson,_Baseball_Player,_from_World's_Champions,_Series_1_(N28)_for_Allen_&_Ginter_Cigarettes_MET_DP838205.jpg) on wikipedia commons for comparison.  The pattern is a kind of stochastic stipple pattern, but entirely hand drawn.

Comment: It's such a beautiful technique. Not just a reproduction of an original, but an original in itself. Why are we so lazy in our time? 